# Populate a hyperlink attributed string for UIActivityViewController activities

Tags: html, ios, nsstring

There are lots of answers on SO that show devs how to make a string from HTML content or place a URL in a string, but my question is how to make an HTML string.

I'm trying to create a string that will return in HTML format or at least not show the URL.

So for example web devs would do this to hide the URL:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Visit Us at Google.com!</a>
```

I can easily translate that to a string by doing so:

```
NSString *urlLink = @"www.google.com";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Visit Us at %@", urlLink];
```

But that doesn't replace the link with a hyperlink word of my choosing.

I'm aware that the device dictates if its a hyperlink depending on how you display it. i.e., text fields, text views, or you can force open it etc.

What i'm trying to do is:

```
#define APPSTORELINK @"www.appstorelink.com"

@implementation Config

+(NSString *)appstorelink {
return APPSTORELINK;
}

+(NSString *)mmsmetadata {
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I shared this publication with the <a href=\"http://%@\">[Name of my iPhone App] iPhone App</a>", APPSTORELINK];
return string;
}
```

So I can easily call it here or app wide:

```
NSArray *shareItems;
UIImage *snapshot = [self imageFromView:self.view];
shareItems = @[[Config mmsmetadata], snapshot];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
[activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:(UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)^(NSString *string, BOOL completed) {
```

So in short, how can I make the string HTML format out of the box? My main concern is I want to hide the URL and replace it with an HTML tag, or otherwise if you have a better solution. Can't find anything on SO.

Any thoughts? I'm probably overthinking this. I'm sure theres an easier way

**EDIT**

Before even posting I have been aware of NSAttributedString and that was the first thing I attempted. However, the issue isn't setting an attribute, thats the easy part, the part that is defining my question is how to set it so it will *DISPLAY* as attributed when using activities in the UIActivityViewController

Here is how I set it, but the outcome was the same as above so I figured it would be easier to use an HTML tag:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I shared this publication with the Army Pubs iPhone App!"];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [string length]);

NSURL *linkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APPSTORELINK];

[string beginEditing];
[string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
               value:linkURL
               range:selectedRange];

[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
               value:[UIColor blueColor]
               range:selectedRange];

[string addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
               value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
               range:selectedRange];
[string endEditing];
return string;
```

However, it still displays as plain text in the Message or Mail composers. So think MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate how there is a setting for isHTML. If it's set to yes it strips all the HTML tags and displays the text as a hyperlink. For example:

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
 [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
```

I want to emulate that when the activities are called from within a UIActivityViewController

This is the output currently even if I do it with the attributed string I tried first it just displays as plain text by stripping the HTML tag but doesn't make it a link

[image: message app]

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: I have not @Ada I haven't even looked at the docs in about a year. I'm guessing it could be possible now the way Apple introduced rich links in the new iMessage and most recent OS. I'll have to take a look later

Answer (score 0):

See  link option in [attributed strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2).

> The link attribute specifies an arbitrary object that is passed to the NSTextView method 
>   clickedOnLink:atIndex: when the user clicks in the text range
>   associated with the NSLinkAttributeName attribute. The text view’s
>   delegate object can implement textView:clickedOnLink:atIndex: or
>   textView:clickedOnLink: to process the link object. Otherwise, the
>   default implementation checks whether the link object is an NSURL
>   object and, if so, opens it in the URL’s default application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it was the first thing I tried, however, my question title was off putting, so I altered to reflect my goal. I think it was asking how to make an clickable part of a string, thats the easy part, i just don't know how to make it display that way when using MFMessageComposeViewController or UIActivityViewController sharedItems. I really don't want to just add the URL but I guess I might have to